# How do I set the date format for logcat messages in Android Studio?

Tags: android, logcat

The date format in Logcat for Android Studio is in the format mm-dd.

How do I change it to yyyy-mm-dd or dd-mm or whatever I want?

[image: Logcat date output]

Answer (score 0):

you can change the date format by using

`adb logcat -v time | \
sed 's/\(..\)-\(..\)[^\w]*\(..\):\(..\):\(..\).\(...\)\(.*\)/\1_\2_\3_\4_\5_\6:\7/g'`

It is to let `adb logcat` displays time by `-v time`; then use `sed` to convent time into format you want.

more about adb formatting.
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#outputFormat

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But this is concerning logcat standalone.  Am I right?  How do we configure this from within Android Studio?